# rails_admin without devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, rails-admin

I'm having hard time getting rails_admin to work without devise.

I tried https://gist.github.com/Overbryd/1068094
as well removing all the devise related code from my user model and routes

However, I'm getting the following error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (Could not find a valid mapping for # From here
6: - if _current_user
7: - if user_link = edit_user_link
8: %li= user_link
9: - if logout_path.present?
10: %li= link_to content_tag('span', t('admin.misc.log_out'), :class => 'label label-important'), logout_path, :method => Devise.sign_out_via
11: - if _current_user.respond_to?(:email) && _current_user.email.present?

devise (2.2.3) lib/devise/mapping.rb:42:in find_scope!'
/home/eugene/.bundler/ruby/1.9.1/rails_admin-75079da0906e/app/helpers/rails_admin/application_helper.rb:36:inlogout_path'
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a route similar to this:

```
get "logout" => "sessions#destroy", as: "logout"
```

Then you can do this:

```
  - if _current_user
    - if user_link = edit_user_link
      %li= user_link
    %li= link_to content_tag('span', t('admin.misc.log_out'), class: 'label label-important'), '/logout'
```

That simply replaces the Devise nonsense with a link to your overall sessions destroy route. You can also delete the logout_path method in the Application Controller as well.